# How to edit specific value in binary file?

Tags: c++

I have a structure of flight, which is being writing into binary file and i want to edit flight destination and i have no idea how to do it. 
This is my code for getting user input and writting to binary file.

```
struct Flight_Details {
    char destination[99];
    char departure[99];
    char time_depart[80];
    char time_arrive[80];
    int flight_number;
};

switch (menu)
        {
            case MENU::NEW_FLIGHT: {
                Flight_Details flight_d;
                cout << "Enter Departure: ";
                cin >> flight_d.destination;
                cout << "Enter Destination: ";
                cin >> flight_d.departure;
                cout << "Enter Departure Time: ";
                cin >> flight_d.time_depart;
                cout << "Please enter arriving time: ";
                cin >> flight_d.time_arrive;
                cout << "Flight Number: ";
                cin >> flight_d.flight_number;

                ofstream file;
                file.open("Flgiht_Details.data", ios::binary);

                if (!file) cout << "Could create/open file";
                else {
                    file.write((char*)&flight_d, sizeof(flight_d));
                    file.close();
                }
                break;
            }
            case MENU::OUTPUT_FILE: {

                ifstream readFile;
                readFile.open("Flgiht_Details.data");
                if (!readFile) cout << "Couldn't open file";
                else {
                    readFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
                    int fileSize = readFile.tellg();
                    int countOfFlights = fileSize / sizeof(Flight_Details);
                    readFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

                    Flight_Details* flight = new Flight_Details[countOfFlights];
                    readFile.read((char*)flight, countOfFlights *sizeof(Flight_Details));
                    readFile.close();

                    for (int i = 0; i < countOfFlights; i++)
                    {
                        cout << flight[i].destination << "\n" << flight[i].departure << "\n" << flight[i].time_depart << "\n" << flight[i].time_arrive << "\n" << flight[i].flight_number << "\n\n";
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            case MENU::EDIT: {
                Flight_Details* flight_d;
                ifstream readFile;
                readFile.open("Flgiht_Details.data");
                if (!readFile) cout << "Couldn't open file";
                else {
                    readFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
                    int fileSize = readFile.tellg();
                    int countOfFlights = fileSize / sizeof(Flight_Details);
                    readFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

                    Flight_Details* flight = new Flight_Details[countOfFlights];
                    readFile.read((char*)flight, countOfFlights * sizeof(Flight_Details));
                    readFile.close();

                    ofstream file;
                    char edit[50];
                    cout << "Edit: ";
                    cin.getline(edit, 50);

                    for (int i = 0; i < countOfFlights; i++)
                    {
                        if (strcmp(flight_d[i].destination, edit) == 0)
                        {
                            //edit file
                        }
                    }

                }
            }       
        }
```

Comment: Seek and write. Better: use SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Flight_Details` has a fixed size in bytes when written, it is easy to calculate where in the file each flight is. The general equation is `flight_number * sizeof(Flight_Details)//where flight_number is 0..N`. This will calculate a byte offset into the file to seek to. From there it is just a matter of reading exactly `sizeof(Flight_Details)` bytes from the file and converting that buffer into a `Flight_Details` which in this case could mean that you just fill each buffer in the `Flight_Details` with the bytes manually, or if you prefer you could just `reinterpret_cast()` the `char*` of data into the right type(this will only be a decent idea if your buffer is exactly `sizeof(Flight_Details)` long. It would be safer to just manually copy the bytes in via a constructor of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you will write under `// edit file` comment. This looks ugly but it works pretty fine

```
cout << "Yeah we are editing\n";
char newdestiny[99];
cout << "new dest: ";
cin.getline(newdestiny, 99);
strcpy(flight[i].destination, newdestiny);
file.write((char*)flight, sizeof(Flight_Details[countOfFlights]));
file.close();
return 0;
```

and you have got bugs in your program like when you ask for desparture you are getting destination and when you open `file` for writing that data you have to include `ios::app` flag so you can enter new flight information as well(?)

the file I am opening has only `ios::out` flag

and one more thing `strcmp(flight_d[i].destination, edit) == 0` line should  be `strcmp(flight[i].destination, edit) == 0`

Comment: its gives an error when writing to file, that countOfFlights must have a constant value

Comment: strange didn't give any error to me. what compiler you are using? or maybe change countOfFlights to `const int`